# How to correctly rewrite @StreamListener

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to correctly rewrite the annotation from previous version: `@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)`.

This was rewritten to:

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> processMessage() {
        return message -> {
```

However, I am not getting any messages, because obviously, I need to define the binding in the properties file. How should I define it?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        processMessage-in-0:
          destination:
            "sink"
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the destination on the binding to the Kafka topic where you expect the records to come from.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        processMessage-in-0:
          destination: <input-kafka-topic>
```

Replace `<input-kafka-topic>` with the proper Kafka topic.